# Passing generic variables to nested functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to write type definitions for an "async-route" wrapper for express.js. I'm new to typescript, just learned about generics.

As the function could be called behind middlewares that extend the default express `Request` I want to create it so users can provide their own extended "Request".

So far I have gotten to:

`asyncRoute.ts`

```
import { NextFunction } from 'express';

type Fn = <R, S>(req: R, res: S, next?: NextFunction) => Promise<any>;

export default function asyncRoute<R, S> (fn: Fn) {
  return function asyncRouteWrap(req: R, res: S, next: NextFunction) {
    Promise.resolve(fn<R,S>(req, res, next)).catch(next);
  };
};
```

Usage:

```
import { Request } from 'express';

interface AppRequest extends Request {
  log: Logger;
  // ...other stuff
}

router.get(
  '/',
  asyncRoute<AppRequest, AppResponse>(async (req, res) => {
    req.log.info('test');
  })
);
```

But I get `Property 'log' does not exist on type 'Request'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the TypeScript compiler cannot infer the type of `req` in the anonymous function parameter of `asyncRouter`. If you have IDE support for TypeScript you will see that `fn<R, S>(req, res, next)` does not have `R` bound to `AppRequest` (in VS Code you only need to hover over the specific line of code).

You can solve your problem by explicitely adding type parameters to `Fn` in your definition of `asyncRoute`. For this, you need to first add type parameters to your type definition for `Fn`

```
type Fn<R, S> = (req: R, res: S, next?: NextFunction) => Promise<any>
```

and then define `asyncRoute` as follows

```
export default function asyncRoute<R, S> (fn: Fn<R, S>) { 
  return function asyncRouteWrap(req: R, res: S, next: NextFunction) {
    Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);
  };
};
```

The type error should be gone now.

---

Here's a [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20NextFunction%20%3D%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Fn%3CR%2C%20S%3E%20%3D%20(req%3A%20R%2C%20res%3A%20S%2C%20next%3F%3A%20NextFunction)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3Cany%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20default%20function%20asyncRoute%3CR%2C%20S%3E%20(fn%3A%20Fn%3CR%2C%20S%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20function%20asyncRouteWrap(req%3A%20R%2C%20res%3A%20S%2C%20next%3A%20NextFunction)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Promise.resolve(fn(req%2C%20res%2C%20next)).catch(next)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%2F%20...%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Request%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20log%3A%20Logger%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Logger%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20info(s%3A%20string)%3A%20any%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20AppRequest%20extends%20Request%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20log%3A%20Logger%3B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20...other%20stuff%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20AppResponse%20%3D%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20router%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get(path%2C%20fn)%3A%20any%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Arouter.get(%0D%0A%20%20'%2F'%2C%0D%0A%20%20asyncRoute%3CAppRequest%2C%20AppResponse%3E(async%20(req%2C%20res)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20req.log.info('test')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%0D%0A)%3B) with the full code. This contains a few mocked interfaces/types but I'm sure you'll get the point.